# How does porofessor get data about the buffs?

Tags: riot-games-api

I was thinking about coding a customized app similar to [porofessor](https://porofessor.gg) that looks at in game data and analyzes it. The main feature I am looking for is the buff timers that porofessor adds on your map. Does anyone know how they get real-time information about when I kill a certain jungle monster. Furthermore, they also get information about when the enemy jungler killed their buffs, but those timers appear only when you step into vision of those jungle camps. Does anyone know how it works?

The live client data api provides lots of real-time information, but it does not have an event trigger for when jungle monsters are killed I believe
The riot spectator api only provides data about the game itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be acquired locally using memory reading.
You can use a verified library such as Overwolf (https://overwolf.github.io/api/games/events/league-of-legends#jungle_camps) - as far as I know porofessor is also using Overwolf.

Another approach would be to try to read the memory yourself, which I can't recommend as this might get your account banned.